# Minting NFTs failed

Tags: solidity, remix, nft

I'm new to solidity and smart contract development. I'm using openzeppelin's ERC721 contract and trying to generate an NFT. I want to require 0.1ETH for the minting of the token.

```
    function mint() payable public {
        require(msg.value == 1 * (10 ** 17)); // 0.1 eth
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        super._safeMint(tx.origin, tokenId);
    }
```

I'm getting an error that says that the called function should be payable and the value should be less than my current balance.  The balance on the Javascript VM is 99 eth.  The function is payable and there is enough ETH...

What am i doing wrong?

Looking more closely at the transaction data i see that the value is 0 wei. In remix, how do I execute the function and pass it eth as well?  I know I can do it in truffle with a test

```
let nft_mint = await nft.mint_nft(1, {from:accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toBN("100000000000000000")});
```

How do i do that in remix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer value in Remix by adding the amount in section `value` within the "*Deploy & Run transactions*" section. Note that just on the right of this field, you can select the units in ether, wei, etc.

[image]

By the way, this error message you get is quite generic. I've had it for a number of multiple reasons not always related with payable functions or amounts, but in your case, that could be the reason.

Comment: wow do i feel dumb... Thanks!

Comment: I believe that almost everyone in this forum has gone though the same issue ;)